# WPF checkbox in Expander header is not clickable with wpf toolkit theme

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, silverlight

I am displaying some data in an items control.  The ItemTemplate is a button containing an expander control.  i further modify the expander's header to include a checkbox.  If i do not use the Wpf theme, i am able to check and uncheck the checkbox.  if do use a theme, i am not able to do so...

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="../../Resources/Themes/BureauBlue.xaml"/>

<ItemsControl Name="icTS" ItemsSource="{Binding TimeSeriesData}" Grid.Row="0">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Click="Button_Click">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Expander IsExpanded="{Binding IsExpanded}">
                            <Expander.Header>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsSelected}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Ticker}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Expander.Header>
....
....
```

How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: Why would you embed an Expander in a Button anyway? It almost seems like an Accordion control might be a better option for this scenario.

Comment: to be able to click anywhere and have it drop down.  may not be the best approach...but any solution to  my problem you can recommend?